# Host forwarding fails, server is up, domain name tests ambiguous

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ip-forwarding

I have a domain name registered with http://www.registryrocket.com/

[image: setup forwarding for hostgator.]

The "main" site, which is called rudolfcode.net, is registered under godaddy, and forwards to a heroku site (rudolfcode.herokuapp.com).

I have found that the main site, rudolfcode.net works, but the hostgator forwarding has stopped working (firefox simply fails when you point to http://www.rudolflabs.com, which is the domain name registered by hostgator).

How can I debug this issue ?

Finally, I have tried to run some DNS tests, and here are the results :

[image: dns test results : some important failures]

Im not sure what the failures mean .... But Im pretty sure that "Conecting to WWW Home Page" failed is a pretty bad sign !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems pretty flawed. Maybe you should look into the general use of [DNS](https://serverfault.com/tags/dns/info).

First of all you use URL Redirect on registryrocket a lot. I'm not sure that is what you want.

You want to make an alias of for your heroku app. That is done with a `cname`.

Then registryrocket cannot redirect the traffic of "rudolflabs.net" if it is not the nameserve for this domain. But you said that this domain is hosted by hostgator. So you might be able to set the NS records of your hostgator domain to the registryrocket nameservers. Otherwise you have to set every record from each hoster.

Finally the address http://www.rudolflabs.com worls and redirects me to http://rudolfcode.herokuapp.com/Home.html

Comment: (1) In any case, I do believe registryrocket.com is the nameserver, because that is who i purchased the domain from. and (2) What is the advantage of using CNAME over a URL-REDIRECT ?

Comment: (1) Sorry I confused the .net domain with the .com domain. I edited it. (2)In short: A records=domain name to IPv4 Address, CNAME=Alternative name for the A record. So essentially the Heroko App has the name "rudolfcode.herokuapp.com" then you just set a cname from rudolflabs.com to rudolfcode.herokuapp.com. This will not redirect your browser but give them the same IP as if you had used rudolfcode.herokuapp.com in the browser.